Given $f \in L^p_{\text{loc}}$ and $\phi \in S$ (Schwartz class), do we have that $f \ast \phi \in C^\infty$? What if $f,\phi$ have compact support?
Context. Consider the usual Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^n$ and let $L^p_{\operatorname{loc}}$ denote the space of measurable functions that are locally $p$-integrable on $\mathbb R^n$, with $1 \leqslant p \leqslant \infty$. Moreover, let $C^k$ denote the space of functions defined on $\mathbb R^n$ that are $k$ times continuously differentiable, where $k \geqslant 1$ is an integer. As usual, define $C^\infty$ to be the intersection of all $C^k$ and let $C_c$ denote the space of continuous functions on $\mathbb R^n$ with compact support. Furthermore, let $C_c^\infty = C_c \cap C^\infty$. Finally, denote by $S$ the usual Schwartz space of functions that consists of all the functiosn in $C^\infty$ which, togheter with their derivatives, vanish at infinity faster than any power of $|x|$.
I am interested in knowing if the following two claims are true (I highly suspect they are but can't find a specific reference for such results).
Claim $1$.  Given two functions $f \in L^p_{\operatorname{loc}}$ and $\phi \in S$, there holds $f \ast \phi \in C^\infty.$
Claim $2$.  Given two functions $f \in L^p_{\operatorname{loc}}$ and $\phi \in S$ such that both $f$ and $\phi$ have compact support, there holds $f \ast \phi \in C^\infty_c.$
My investigation. As I've already indicated above, I highly believe that both these results are true, altought I wasn't able to find a proper reference for them.  Despite this, I found some similar results in the literature. For example, in the book "Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations", written by Brezis, the author proves the following results (cf. Proposition $4.20$):

If $f \in C^\infty_c$ and $g \in L^1_{\operatorname{loc}}$, then $f
 \ast g \in C^\infty$.

The last result is interesting because it allows us to conclude that if $f \in C^\infty_c$ and $g \in L^p_\text{loc}$, then $f \ast  g \in C^\infty$ (recall the inclusion $L^p_{\text{loc}} \subset L^1_{\text{loc}}$, for every $1 \leqslant p \leqslant \infty$). This is similar to Claim $1$, but not yet what I wish.
The statement that makes me believe that the claims above are true is one provided by Folland in his famous book "Real Analysis: Modern  Techniques and Their Applications" which says the following:

One of the most important properties of convolution is that, roughly speaking, $f \ast g$ is at least as smooth as either $f$ or $g$.

I wonder if someone can confirm the validity of my claims above and provide a reference that explicitly states this results.
Thanks for any help in advance.

For claim 1 you need the convolution to be well-defined, which is the case as long as $g$ doesn’t grow too quickly. In particular, $L^p_{loc}$ isn’t enough - consider $f$ a Gaussian and $g = 1/f$, then the convolution is infinite at zero. But assuming $f$ is small at infinity ($L^1$ is enough) you can show the convolution is smooth by differentiating under the integral sign (you can justify this by appealing to the dominated convergence theorem and using the mean value theorem to pointwise bound the difference quotients). Claim 2 follows directly.

Notice that the Schwartz functions with compact support are exactly the $\mathcal{C}^\infty_c$ functions, since being $0$ outside of a compact set gives you the Schwartz condition for free and the Schwartz condition doesn't matter if the support is compact. And still on claim $2$, we do have that $\operatorname{supp} f * \phi \subset \operatorname{supp} f + \operatorname{supp} \phi$, so claim $2$ would be true with the result you mentioned.

@kieransquared Thanks for your comment. I make you the same question I made to Lieven in response to his answer. If we let $f \in L^p_{\text{loc}}$ and $\phi \in S \cap L^1$ such that $| \phi |_1 = 1$, can we guarantee that $f \ast g \in C^\infty$ ?

@BrunoB Thanks for your comment. Can you confirm that the second claim remains true if we take $\phi \in C_c^\infty$ instead of $\phi \in S$ with compact support ?

There is zero difference for the reason I mentioned: the main condition for being a Schwartz function is only tested at infinity. If the function is zero outside of a compact set, then it's Schwartz iff it's infinitely differentiable.

Claim 1 is false. If neither function has to have compact support, then the convolution may not be well-defined, e.g., take $\phi\in S$ nowhere zero, and $f=1/\phi$ which is continuous and therefore locally integrable for any $p\in[1,\infty].$
Claim 2 is true by elementary properties of the derivatives of convolutions.

This makes sense. Do you think the validity of Claim $1$ becomes true if we additionally assume that $\phi \in L^1$ with $| \phi |_1 = 1 $ ? Furthermore, Claim $2$ is also true if we let $\phi \in C_c^\infty$ instead of $\phi \in S$ with compact support, correct?

The requirement $\phi\in L^1$ does not help; in fact my counterexample can satisfy this requirement, take for example the Gaussian bell curve in dimension $n=1.$ What you need is a restriction on the growth of $f,$ for example bounded in absolute value by a polynomial.

I do not understand the difference between $C_c^\infty$ and $S$ with compact support.

Thanks for your quick response. I am not sure if there is any difference between $C_c^\infty$ and $S$ with compact support (Bruno's comment above seems to suggest that there is no difference between these sets). In this case, Claim $2$ also holds if we assume that $\phi \in C_c^\infty$ instead of $\phi \in S$ with compact support. Are you also suggesting that there is no difference between these sets?

As sets they are identical. The definition of $C_c^\infty$ is infinite differentiability and compact support. The definition of $S$ is infinite differentiability and rapid descent at infinity. Compact support means zero outside of a bounded set, which is an extreme form of rapid descent at infinity.

As topological spaces they are different, but that does not play a role in the point we were discussing.
